# Is it possible to use SP Modal Dialogs in App Pages?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, modal-dialog, provider-hosted-app

I have a provider hosted App and need to use modals in my App Pages. Is it possible to use SP Modal Dialogs from SP.UI.Dialog.js ?

What JS files are required to be included?

Answer (score 2):

Never done it myself but I don't see any reason for why it can't done.

> This sample shows how to build user interfaces in SharePoint-hosted
>   apps that use the callout and dialog controls.

Check this out,

[SharePoint 2013: Use list views, callouts, and dialogs in SharePoint-hosted apps](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Use-list-cb3e4e14)

I don't have SharePoint 2013 component installed but if you look at solution provided in link in `Default.aspx` page you will find reference to this which means you can use it in apps.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

It's not possible, you might be able to trick SharePoint but then you will need to make changes to host web as described in this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f8dc50cc-4e8f-498b-940e-849c4b61f555/showing-a-modal-popup-dialog-box-in-parent-window-from-an-app-part).

Comment: Your example is related to SharePoint-hosted App, but my question is about Provider-hosted App.

Comment: @Warlock why is it not tagged as Provider-hosted then? Where do you mention Provider Hosted?

Comment: @RobertLindgren It was mentioned at the beginning of my question :) Thanks for the tag.

Comment: @Warlock, my blindness is astonishing ;)

Comment: @Warlock based on the search I just did seems like what you are trying to do is not possible, unless you do some trick as described in the last post of this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f8dc50cc-4e8f-498b-940e-849c4b61f555/showing-a-modal-popup-dialog-box-in-parent-window-from-an-app-part

Comment: @MuhammadRaja In the post you have been provided the author found a way by using HTML5 PostMessage API. I'm working with App Pages (not iframes), so I have no a parent window. In my situation the challenge looks impossible  :(

Comment: @Warlock Use jquery/ajax "post" method then ?

Comment: @MuhammadRaja Cannot understand you. PostMessage is not a POST request, it's just a javascript message that iframe can send to a parent window to communicate in borders of the Same Origin Policy.